# Does MongoClient work on pymongo2.3?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a very straight forward question. 
I am trying to connect to MongoDB using pymongo 2.3. I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name MongoClient
```

However import pymongo works fine and pymongo.version yields '2.3'. And python version is 2.7.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation says MongoClient was introduced in a later version (2.4). Your pymongo seems outdated. Try removing it, then installing it with pip:

```
pip install pymongo
```

Comment: hmm i guessed that. Thanks for the confirmation.